# How can i add boxicons in the bullet and numbering in my website?

Tags: html, css, tags, bootstrap-5

I don't know how to add boxicons in bullets and numbering. First i write in index to add boxicons and it's not hapening and i tried in style page but I can't get it done in correct order.

Comment: can you attach your code, please?

Comment: I have done this in index page                                                                                             <i class="bx bx-store-alt"></i> and this in style.css page                                             .list{
      list-style: none;
  }
  It placed at the top of the paragraph not in bulletin points

Comment: or should i attach more code about its section

Comment: writing only the description is difficult to understand your problem. If you attach related code in the questioned section it will be easy to review your question.

Comment: can i attached my code in this comment? I am new to this so give me instruction

Comment: just copy your relevant code and paste it with the edit option.

Comment: Welcome to SO and have a look at how to ask a good question which will improve your chances of getting a helpful answer. Including your code in the question will help others to reproduce the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.